# Careers: Explain Markdown Line Break Syntax in "Projects and Links" Description Box

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

When I entered a few sites into the "Projects and Links" section of my Careers CV, I noticed that every other link (starting with the 2nd one) wasn't being linked. I quickly realized that the problem was with my not having entered blank lines between each link in the input box, as it's Markdown. However, users who aren't familiar with Markdown syntax might not realize why some of their input is acting weirdly.

While there is already an "editing help" link underneath the input box, I think that you need to add an explicit note in the yellow description box that describes the correct line break syntax.